# multiple attribute selector exclude class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following selector which selects every element that is required plus one additional that has a class of "formValue" which I want to exclude

```
$("[data-OriginalValue][data-OriginalValue!=''][data-TaskItemID]")
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: What is the "formValue" that you want to exclude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is chain a `.not()` to your jQuery selector; read more about it in the jQ docs here:
http://api.jquery.com/not/

Example:

```
$("[data-OriginalValue][data-OriginalValue!=''][data-TaskItemID]").not('.formValue')
```

Here's a basic CodePen illustrating the behavior:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrqWgv

In that example, there's an element that matches your selector but also has the class `formValue`; using the `.not` function removes it (and any element with a class of `formValue`) from the collection returned by the selector preceding it.